# Xcode11 Editors (via "Add Editor to Right") are disabled

Tags: xcode, xcode11

It has been working all this while since I upgraded to `Xcode11.2`. A couple of days back noticed it and now it's not allowing me to add an editor to the layout. Similar to [Editor changes introduced in Xcode 11](https://www.avanderlee.com/xcode/xcode-assistant-editor/).

Tried:

- Restarting Xcode
- Rebooting MacBook
- No Xcode update pending in AppStore

Any other suggestions to try before reinstalling the Xcode?

Current State for Xcode:

- Disabled Editor add option

[image: Disabled Editor add option on right panel]

- Disabled Editor option via Menu->Editor

[image: Disabled Editor in Xcode->Menu->Edit option]

## Update A:

- After using "Adjust Editor Option"

[image: Using Adjust Editor Option]

[image: Adjust editor options - Assistent showing]

This Assistant is not the same as regular editor. 
An editor would allow the user to independently open any file (and not always show to counterpart files). Plenty of visual space as using external monitor 24".

## Update 2:

It seems to be an issue with the current project only (perhaps some messed up `.xcodeproj` setting?). Opened another project, and I'm able to see the "Add editor on right" just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 157, accepted):

## Unfocus the Editor

Turned out to be that Editor was in focused mode. As soon as an editor is in focused mode, Xcode hides the other editors and disables "adding editors to right" option on the menu and right bar.

Use the following key combination to toggle the focus-unfocus the editor.

`Control + Shift + Command + Enter`

Or use the [image: Shortcut button to unfocus editor]

Answer (score 15):

## Assistant Editor

Assistant is now under the `editor option` menu (left itme).

[image: Preview]

Also you can use <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> shortcut

## Add Editor

The other one that is disabled is *Add Editor on Right*. Some times its getting disabled because there is not enough space to show another editor. You can change the position of it to **below** by holding <kbd>option</kbd> and click. This will convert it to ***Add Editor Below***

[image: Add Editor Below]

Comment: Tried the suggestion. It does open the Assistant which is more restrictive (can't have more than 1 assistant editors open). Updated question with other details. Please take another look.

Comment: Did you try holding option key?

Comment: Yes, it did add the assistant editor (which is not same as regular editor).

Comment: Looking for adding multiple editors with "add editor on right" option. Similar to [guide here] (https://www.avanderlee.com/xcode/xcode-assistant-editor/)

Comment: I mean holding option and click on the disabled button. Also it would be more helpful if you post fullscreen images I think

Comment: Yes, tried that (holding option and clicking on it) it doesn't add anything. Similarly, shortcut `Control + Command + T` doesn't add it.