# My split screen button is not working in Xcode. I have tried all the solutions possible. Is there any way to fix this?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, storyboard, xcode12

I cannot open another an assistent editor in Xcode, the top right plus button is greyed out (see screenshot).

- I tried everything that may work to my knowledge.
- I tried quitting and again force quitting Xcode.
- I tried restating my computer
- I finally tried to open the ViewController in AppCode in a different window and tried to connect the IBOutlet that way and Nothing worked

here is a ScreenShot
[image]

Comment: What is "my split screen button"? What is "not working"?

Comment: This is a legit question, the issue is very confusing if you are new to Xcode. I vote for reopening.

Comment: The question is currently closed so I cannot post a proper answer. But click on the little icon with arrows pointing to toward each other in the top left above your editor view. It will "Unfocus" the editor. Keyboard: Command-Control-Shift-Return

Comment: @de. in that case, duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/59186051/341994

Comment: @matt - agreed.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you mean you cant open the Assistant editor. If so then:

- Open story board
- Know which file you want to open in the side by side view, aka
  assistant editor
- option click or control click with your mouse on the desired file,
  then it will automatically open the file in the side view for you
- Additionally you may also want to make sure you have linked correct
  files to your views in storyboard.